# Unable to Call post,put method in angular js

Tags: php, angularjs, post

I can successfully make a GET call to my service using CORS. However, something must be going wrong at the preflight level for the POST, PUT, and DELETE.I am on angular js I have tried every thing put on server side header .like

```
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
  $res = $app->response();
 // $origin=$app->request->headers->get("ORIGIN") ? $app->request->headers->get("ORIGIN"):'*';
  // $origin = $app->request->getHeader("ORIGIN") ? $app->request->getHeader("ORIGIN") : '*';
    $res->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $res->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    // $res->header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true"); 
    $res->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'x-requested-with, content-type');
    $res->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
     $res->header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400'); 

    $res->write(json_encode($response));
```

when I try to use post method using cross domain it give me error like this

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Any help would be appreciated.Only get function is working on cross scripting why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" -> "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept".
```